# Meteor functionality to check for existing user in Meteor.users?

Tags: meteor, coffeescript

How does this code look? Pretty solid and efficient? Any way I could do this better?
EDIT: Forgot to mention, I'm checking as a user fills out a signup form, before they hit submit to actually create the account.

### Template HTML:

```
...
<input id="username">
{{#if usernameTaken}}
  <div class="error">Username is taken.</div>
{{/if}}
...
```

### Client:

```
Template.signupPage.events
  'blur #username': (e) ->
    username = $(e.target).val()

    Meteor.call 'userExists', username, (error, result) ->
      Session.set 'usernameTaken', result.exists

Template.signupPage.helpers
  usernameTaken: ->
    return Session.get('usernameTaken')
```

### Server:

```
Meteor.methods
  userExists: (username) ->
    check username, String

    results = Meteor.users.find
      username:
        $regex: "^#{username}$", $options: 'i'

    return { exists: results.count() > 0 }
```

Comment: Add limit 1 to your `find` (or rewrite your code to use `findOne` instead) to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

On the client-side, there's a potentially confusing interaction here. In the example, "myusername" is taken, but "myusername1" is not.

1. User types in "myusername" and then blurs the field
2. Client makes a method call to see if "myusername" is taken
3. User changes their mind, changes the field to "myusername1" and blurs the field
4. Client makes a method call to see if "myusername1" is taken
5. The first method call returns, and "Username is taken" appears
6. A reasonably long time passes
7. The second method call returns, and "Username is taken" disappears

If the user doesn't wait for the "reasonably long time", they'll probably think the "Username is taken" refers to "myusername1" and not "myusername".

I'd take some steps against this:

- Display "Checking username availability..." while the method call is in progress. Replace it with e.g. "myusername is taken" or "myusername1 is available" when the method returns. Use colour and icons appropriately.
- If the method call is in progress and the user types anything in the field, even if they didn't blur the field yet, then hide the "Checking username availability". When the out-of-date method call returns, ignore the result.
- If it says "#{username} is (taken|available)" and the user types anything in the field, even if they didn't blur the field yet, then hide that text.

Comment: "When the out-of-date method call returns, ignore the result." Is there a mechanism in place for this? Or do I manually have to set Session variables to track if the callback should be ignored or not?

Comment: I found another issue: when submitting the form and creating a new user, the warning "Username is taken" shows up because apparently the account creation took place so quickly, and the username availability check lagged behind it. So before I call my `createSeller` method, I can just do `Session.set('creatingUser', true)` and in the `blur #username` block, I immediately return if `creatingUser` is `true`.

Comment: Easy way: disable the username input field while it checks validity.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but the accounts API already have built in duplicate username detection as usernames / emails should be unique.

So you could also rely on `Accounts.createUser` ([see the doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser)):

```
Accounts.createUser({username:..., email:..., password:...}, function(error, result){
  //you will get an error if the username already exists
});
```

Comment: True. In this case, I'm checking for duplicate username when the user tabs out of the username field, not when the account is actually created.

Comment: In this case I don't see any other way to do it except by doing a request to the DB as you did :)

Comment: @Guillaume You can't use this server side. The callback on user creation is not implemented yet on server side.